# OkHttp and Retrofit - implicit response caching?

Tags: caching, retrofit, okhttp

I'm using Retrofit to communicate with a simple REST API. I know that OkHttp can be configured to use a cache, and as far as I can see in their documentation, there should only be response caching if you explicitly give it a cache (e.g. LruCache).

In my case if the server is not allowing caching, it takes around 5 seconds for the response to arrive. But if `Cache-Control: max-age=300` is enabled, it takes around 50ms for the response to arrive.

So my question is simple: What am I not getting? Where is the cache? Does OkHttp have some implicit response cache anyway?

Or the more obvious alternative: Is this really a server side cache?

```
val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
      .connectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      .readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      .writeTimeout(WRITE_TIMEOUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      .build()

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
      .baseUrl(endpoint)
      .client(okHttpClient)
      .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
      .build()
service = retrofit.create<RetrofitService>(RetrofitService::class.java)
```

I'm using Retrofit 2.3.0 which depends on OkHttp 3.8.0

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was indeed service side caching. Testing this on an emulator with the network throttled to simulate GPRS made it quite obvious.

I'm leaving this question here for future reference.